# error running a code with libstdc++6.dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I was trying to compile and run the following code on my CODE::BLOCKS sftwr but
It could never run properly due to some problems with a dll "libstdc++6.dll"

I leave you the code listing and the error log in debug mode (f8)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv){ 
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    if(!al_init()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    display = al_create_display(640, 480);
    if(!display) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(10.0);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Debug output:

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: c:\telechar\Codeblocks\Mesprojets\MonProjet\
Adding source dir: c:\telechar\Codeblocks\Mesprojets\MonProjet\
Adding file: c:\telechar\Codeblocks\Mesprojets\MonProjet\bin\Debug\MonProjet.exe
Changing directory to: c:/telechar/Codeblocks/Mesprojets/MonProjet/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Telechar\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Telechar\CodeBlocks\MinGW;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common  Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
Starting debugger: C:\Telechar\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args c:/telechar/Codeblocks/Mesprojets/MonProjet/bin/Debug/MonProjet.exe 
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
Child process PID: 5536
Error while reading shared library symbols for c:\telechar\Codeblocks\Mesprojets\MonProjet\libstdc++-6.dll:
...
Error while reading shared library symbols for c:\telechar\Codeblocks\Mesprojets\MonProjet\libstdc++-6.dll:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In al_destroy_display () (c:\telechar\Codeblocks\Mesprojets\MonProjet\allegro-5.0.10-md.dll)
Continuing...
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In al_destroy_display () (c:\telechar\Codeblocks\Mesprojets\MonProjet\allegro-5.0.10-md.dll)
Continuing...
[Inferior 1 (process 5536) exited with code 030000000005]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

the weird thing is that in release mode, it seems to work fine (a window appears for a while then closes itself, in debug mode, the screen displays but it has a blue color instead, at the end, it does crashes)

Comment: It may be related to using a version of Allegro compiled with a GCC version different from the one provided with CodeBlocks. See [this similar question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901930/allegro-5-crashs-on-calling-al-clear-to-colorallegro-color) which points to [this forum thread](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/610189)

Comment: my version de gcc is 4.7.1 , it cames with code::blocks. How could I use a new version of gcc with CD::BLCKS? I tried to donwload the latest version but I do not understand the donwloading process on their website

Comment: On windows you have to install MinGW (the Windows GCC port).

Comment: @Shinobi Do you use a precompiled version of Allegro or did you compile it yourself?

Comment: I use a precompiled version 5.0.10 for mingw 4.7.0, downloaded from the allegro website. I linked it to CODE::BLOCKS

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments of the question, I guess the problem comes from the fact that you use MinGW 4.7.1, provided with CodeBlocks, whereas your Allegro binaries are compiled for MinGW 4.7.0.

According to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901930/allegro-5-crashs-on-calling-al-clear-to-colorallegro-color) which point to [this forum thread](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/610189), the version of the compiler used for Allegro and for your program must be the same. Thus, you can either:

- Download a version of Allegro compiled for MinGW 4.7.1,
- or compile Allegro by yourself, using MinGW 4.7.1,
- or use MinGW 4.7.0 instead of the version provided with CodeBlocks.

Comment: where could I get the one for Mingw 4.7.1? i do not see it on Allegro website